# how to change the text by change the slides in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shiny-reactivity

I want to change the name of the photo in front of the photo by changing each photo from the slide.
But using the following codes, the input id is not displayed at all. The codes are as follow

````
library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui<-    dashboardPagePlus(title="Sample",
    dashboardHeaderPlus(title="Sample"),
          
dashboardSidebar(),
dashboardBody(

fluidRow(column(width=6, 
carousel(
id = "AA",
carouselItem(
caption = "Image1",
tags$img(src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/Img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=a010291124bf", height = 400, width = 400, align="center")
),
carouselItem(
caption = "Image2",
tags$img(src = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png", height = 400, width = 400, align="center")
))), 
column(width=6, uiOutput("Text"))
     )
)
)
server<- function(input, output, session) {
output$Text<-renderText({
Text<-input$AA
as.character(Text)
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do see them showing up.  It's easier to see if you change the font size and color:

```
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinydashboard)
ui<-    dashboardPagePlus(title="Sample",
                          dashboardHeaderPlus(title="Sample"),
                          
                          dashboardSidebar(),
                          dashboardBody(
                            htmltools::tags$style(
                              ".carousel-caption{
                                font-size: 48px; 
                                color: black;
                              }"
                            ),
                            fluidRow(column(width=6, 
                                            carousel(
                                              id = "AA",
                                              carouselItem(
                                                caption = "Image1",
                                                tags$img(src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/Img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=a010291124bf", height = 400, width = 400, align="center")
                                              ),
                                              carouselItem(
                                                caption = "Image2",
                                                tags$img(src = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png", height = 400, width = 400, align="center")
                                              ))), 
                                     column(width=6, uiOutput("Text"))
                            )
                          )
)
server<- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Text<-renderText({
    Text<-input$AA
    as.character(Text)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I want to show that which image is shown now by input$AA. After that print some details about that image. The main problem is output$Text does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `uiOutput`, try `renderUI` on the server side.  Also, to show different text in each image, you need to define `renderText` and output it in `carouselItem`.  Try this code

```
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinydashboard)
ui<-    dashboardPagePlus(title="Sample",
                          dashboardHeaderPlus(title="Sample"),

                          dashboardSidebar(),
                          dashboardBody(
                                  tags$head(
                                    tags$style(HTML("
                                  #AA{
                                    width:900px;
                                    height:600px;
                                    }
                                .carousel-control{
                                  color:#FF0000;
                                }
                                .carousel-caption{
                                font-size: 48px;
                                color: red;}
                                "))
                                  ),
                            fluidRow(column(width=6,
                                            carousel(
                                              id = "AA",
                                              carouselItem(
                                                caption = "Image1",
                                                textOutput("text1"),
                                                tags$img(src = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/Img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=a010291124bf", height = 400, width = 400, align="center")
                                              ),
                                              carouselItem(
                                                caption = "Image2",
                                                textOutput("text2"),
                                                tags$img(src = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png", height = 400, width = 400, align="center")
                                              ))),
                                     column(width=6, uiOutput("Text"))
                            )
                          )
)
server<- function(input, output, session) {
  output$Text<-renderUI({
    #Text<-as.character(input$AA)
    tagList(
      p("I like to print something over all images", style = "color:blue")
    )
  })
  output$text1 <- renderText("Print something in image 1")
  output$text2 <- renderText("Print something in image 2")

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But my problem is identifying that which image is displayed now. but the input id does not work.

Comment: ok. I am not sure how you plan to identify individual carousel Items using that ID. You can try defining separate textOutputs for each image and then displaying it as shown in the updated answer. Depends on your use case.